# Python pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am using Python 2.7.  I am trying to do the equivalent of a vlookup between a dataframe and a dictionary, but the return value is NaN.  I know the dictionary is recognizing the key and outputting the correct value, but have not been able to figure out why the merge is returning the blank value.

Code:

```
###Cutup Cleanup

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\mbussel\\Desktop\\Machine Learning\\RPReplenish\\Cutup.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
prodLine = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\mbussel\\Desktop\\Machine Learning\\RPReplenish\\ProdLine.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

df1['Grd'] = df1['Grade'].astype(str)
df1['BW'] = df1['Basis Weight'].astype(str)
df1['P_key'] = df1[['Grd', 'BW']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)

pdLine = dict(prodLine[['P_key','GBW']].values)

df1['GBW']=df1.P_key.map(pdLine)
```

The first input file is imported as:
[image]

The input file to create the dictionary:
[image]

The data type for the P_Key value in df1 is an object, not sure if that matters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
MB

Comment: I believe I have found the issue.  The P_key in the dictionary is reflected as a float, whereas the P_key in df1 is a string.  I'm looking to see how to create the dictionary key and value both as strings now vs. values.  I've tried pdLine = dict(prodLine[['P_key','GBW']].astype(str).values))...still researching

Comment: hey @mb12 if you post a textual sample of your df so others can reproduce your data that would help in gettin an answer asap.